# Text value missing in android

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, appium, perfecto

[image: 1]

[Link for closeup look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kOok.jpg)

I am validating Sign In text in android but the value for text in object spy is blank so I am giving the value through `.getattribute='cont-descr'` but while running the script I am not getting the value even from content description.

Please help.

Comment: property name in your snapshot is `content-desc` so try using this attrib.

Comment: yeah tried with content-desc still not getting value by mistake I have added cont-descry here...

Comment: Can somebody help me here its urgent....Its a hybrid application same thing working in native...Any solution?

Comment: Have you tried getText() ?

Comment: Or try getattribute("textContent")